# How to deal with pandas.DatetimeIndex with reticulate?

Tags: python, r, pandas, datetime, reticulate

I want to use the `reticulate` package to call a Python function whose first argument `time` is supposed to be a `pandas.DatetimeIndex` object. In the body of this python function there is a `np.unique(time.year)`.

Within R, I call this function using a `POSIXct` vector. However, this vector is converted by reticulate to a `np.ndarray`. Therefore I get the error

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'year'
```

**Example**

Python code:

```
def year_(time: pandas.DatetimeIndex):
  return(time.year)
```

R code:

```
library(lubridate)
library(reticulate)

vec_dates <- c(now(), now() + dminutes(10))
source_python("year_.py")
year_(vec_dates)
```

What kind of R object should I use for reticulate to understand that this object must be converted to `pandas.DatetimeIndex`? I tried something with `rownames` but these are converted to a string index.

Comment: See https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/blob/e7a311178a5fbe97ee0d073bab0d54fee173120f/tests/testthat/test-python-datetime.R#L33

Comment: Reticulate maps `POSIXct` to numpy `datetime64`

Comment: @danlooo yes this is the issue, I need a DatetimeIndex. I wrote a python wrapper to convert the np.ndarray to pd.DatetimeIndex. It does the job, but I wish I had a pure R solution.